# How to transfer files between a phone device and Windows 11 in a direct simple way?

Tags: usb, windows-11, android, file-sharing, dialog

I want to access my phone device with Android 11 (One Plus 6), from my desktop computer with Windows 11 Home.
According the "Check for updates" tool in Windows 11, my Windows installation is up to date (version 10.0.22621).

I want to connect my phone device via the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP).

I can access my phone device data to some extent with *Microsoft Phone Link* installed both on the PC and the phone device, so I assume the cable is fine, but that's not the connection I want.

I want to access the phone device as I have accessed phone devices in Windows 7, 8 and 10, without installing any software from Microsoft or from anyone else, straightforwardly by connecting the phone device to the computer and getting a notification about the connection so I could tell the computer to allow the connection.

### Things I have tried or considered

- I have tried to connect another device, **One Plus Nord CE 2 Lite 5G** with Android 13 and the same cable, but again I didn't get any notification on either device
- According to Windows 11 Device Manager I don't have ["Portable Devices" described in this article](https://techyorker.com/how-to-fix-mtp-not-working-in-windows-11/)
- I dobut I should download the [MTP setup information file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/portable/the-mtp-setup-information---inf--file) from anywhere because my system is up to date
- A possible workaround is to send an email to myself from the phone device with the images
- A possible workaround is to connect the phone device to an adjacent computer with Linux and, then save the data on a DoK, then move it to Windows.

### My question

How to transfer files between a phone device and Windows 11 in a direct simple way?

### Updates according to answers

I have tried the answers here but I still have the same problem.

- In the One Plus 5 with Androd 11, under **Developer mode**, the only options I have under **Networking >> Select USB Configuration** are: `File Transfer`, `USB tethering`, `MIDI`, `PTP` and `No data transfer`. I have tried each one, each time reconnecting the cable but no connection popup appeared.
- I didn't find `SSHDroid` in Google Play app store but I have found `Termius` by Termius Corporation and `SSH/FTP server - Terminal` by Banana Studio and `ConnectBot` by Kenny Root and a few others, yet I can't understand how to create an SSH server with those mentioned by name; I just need a program that fetches my device's IP address, allows connection on port `2222` and let me create a password for the connection.

Answer (score 4):

You can try enabling developer mode on the phone, which gives access to some USB settings.

From the android.com page [Configure on-device developer options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options):

> **Enable Developer options**
>
> 1. OnePlus 5T and later [go to] Settings > About phone > Build number
> 2. Tap the Build Number option seven times until you see the message `You are now a developer!` This enables developer options on your device.
> 3. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom.

I have seen suggestions that the following item may be somewhere else in the menu tree, but from the above page...

> [Now go to the] **Networking** [section]
> Tap **Select USB Configuration** to specify how you want the computer to identify the device. As shown in figure 5, you can configure devices for charging only, to transfer files (MTP), to transfer pictures (PTP), to use your mobile internet on the PC (RNDIS), or to transfer audio or MIDI files.

You want the **MTP** (Media Transfer Protocol) option.

Your phone should now present the expected dialog when connected to the computer, and if you allow the connection on the phone it ought to appear in File Explorer.

Comment: Android version in my phone device is **11**

Comment: @alhemister - Instead if using a comment to provide that vital information you should edit your question

Comment: Hello @AndrewMorton I misunderstood you before that "File Transfer" is actually "MTP".

Comment: Anyway, even now when disconnecting and reconneting in this state of affrairs, there is no dialogue box.

Answer (score 1):

To access the Android file-system from Windows, install an
SSH server on Android. Mine is SSHDroid, which works very well
for me, and which when started lets you know the IP of the phone
and the port on which it's listening.

The tool on Windows I use is WinSCP. In its Login dialog create a new
site with the IP and port from SSHDroid. Accept the default password
and connect to the phone. Once you locate the folders that interest you,
you may save them for quick access.

Comment: To my great surprise `SSHDroid` has disappeared from Google Play. A pity, as it's a very simple SSH server. You can still find it floating around if you wish by searching for "SSHDroid apk". Otherwise, you should look for SSH servers on Google Play, not clients. Perhaps "SSH/SFTP Server - Terminal" and "SSH Server by AL-SULTAN" are suitable.

Comment: @harrymc So it's not had a change of name to "DroidSSH"?

Comment: Unfortunately not. DroidSSH is an "Open source SSH **client**".

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an SSH server on your OnePlus 5 running Android 11, you can try using Termius, ConnectBot, or SSH/FTP server - Terminal. Here's a general guideline on how to set it up:

Install one of the mentioned SSH apps from the Google Play Store.
Open the app and navigate to the SSH server settings or setup section.
Look for an option to configure the SSH server or enable SSH.
You may find options to set the port number (such as 2222) and configure a password for the SSH connection.
Save the settings and start the SSH server within the app.
The app should display your device's IP address, which you can use to connect to the SSH server from another device or computer.

Keep in mind that the specific steps may vary slightly depending on the app you choose. Make sure to follow any additional instructions provided within the app. Remember to use a strong password for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Check USB Connection: Ensure you are using a working USB cable and that your phone is set to File Transfer (MTP) mode in its notification panel when connected to the computer.

Notification Permission: When you connect your phone to the computer, check the notification on your phone to see if it asks for MTP permission. If it doesn't appear, try changing the USB connection mode or restarting both devices.

For an alternative solution, you can use MobiKin Assistant for Android, a reliable software that enables seamless data transfer between your OnePlus 6 and Windows 11. It allows you to access and manage your phone data, including photos, without complex setups.